# Extended Web application

Tags: security, forms-authentication

For my project I need to convert a Classic mode Authentication WebApplication (name Sharepoint - 8080) to Claims and add Forms Based Authentication to it. For that matter I extended the webapplication to provide the forms based authentication.

The original application has the url doc.test.com:8080. 
As said I extended it with a new IIS website doc.test.com:80 and enabled FBA. I thought everything worked out fine, I was able to log in with the new created users from the sqldatabase but when I try to open a document from doc.test.com:80 I get an error indicating the system cannot find _layouts/Error.aspx in the webapplication Sharepoint - 8080. Looking into the ULS I found that word is trying to open a Login page located at doc.test.com:80/_login/default.aspx. This seems logically to me because the site collection and site were first created on doc.test.com:8080 so those pages will reside in there, but how can I fix this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Pls note the following points:
1) You do not need to extend your web app for FBA. It can be done on one webapp itself.
2) The layouts page is Global and they are not created for each webapp separately.

Comment: Thx for the reply. I know I don't need to extend my web app for FBA, but the main reason I've extended is was to make it available for external use.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix the problem. After I enabled FBA on the original WebApp everything worked out. So basically the internal users of our organisation now have to chose between "Windows Authentication" and "Forms Authentication" nevertheless they won't ever use the forms option. But now the external users get all pages displayed right.